# unordered_map without providing a custom hash function

Tags: c++, unordered-map

can i declare an unordered_map with a key of type pair<int, int> without providing a custom hash function, as long as your compiler and standard library support C++11 or later.?
just like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    // Declare an unordered_map with pair<int, int> as key and int as value
    std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, int> myMap;

    // Example usage:
    myMap[{1, 2}] = 10;
    myMap[{3, 4}] = 20;

    // Accessing values
    int value1 = myMap[{1, 2}];
    int value2 = myMap[{3, 4}];

    return 0;
}
```

as i try it on my macbook with clion, it always suggeste errors like this:
error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'integral_constant<bool, false>::value' "the specified hash does not meet the Hash requirements"
static_assert(__check_hash_requirements<_Key, _Hash>::value,

and chatGPT always say it can work. i'm confused.

Comment: Side note, but not unimportant. Using `std::pair<int,int>` here is just the wronng kind of lazy. `std::pair` is intended to be used as buillding block for other template classes. In all other code you should just declare a struct with two int members and use that throughout your code. `std::pair` doesn't have any semantic meaning while something like `struct vector_2d_t { int x; int  y; }` does. It also avoids a lot of confusion later : no more looking up what `first` and `second` actually mean in your code.

Comment: ChatGPT has been trained on relatively low quality code, it often confuses "C" with "C++" and it certainly doesn't know about "C++" versions. So don't trust that (yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ChatGPT, use a proper reference such as https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash. That page lists all the specializations provided by the standard library, and you can see clearly `std::pair` is not there, so your code cannot possibly work. That page even contains a note saying

> Note: additional specializations for std::pair and the standard
> container types, as well as utility functions to compose hashes are
> available in `boost::hash`

There is at least one important reason for not providing a default implementation for a `std::pair`: we can hardly give a suitable hash function without knowing what the two members mean and how they interact. In fact, many people have emphasized that `std::pair` should be avoided except in templated code because it does not carry any semantic information about its members and if the members happen to be the same type, or one is convertible to the other, it is quite easy to just swap them accidentally. In most cases, using a structure with properly named fields is a better choice. Standard library functions also tend to avoid using a `std::pair` in such cases. For example, for unary transforms, `std::ranges::transform` returns a `std::ranges::in_out_result`, which is a properly named structure with two iterator fields also named properly, instead of returning a `std::pair` of iterators.

Also note that specializing `std::hash<T>` for `T=std::pair<int,int>` is undefined behavior. If for some reason you want to stick to using `std::pair` after all that have been said, and want to provide a hash function, you need to use the third template parameter (i.e. `Hash`) for `std::unordered_map`, instead of specializing `std::hash`.

Comment: thank you very much.
It can be seen that chatGPT is not always correct.

Comment: @BaylorWei Current "AI" systems can only copy-paste snippets of what it have been trained on, but there's no real knowledge about the snippets or the code it shows you. You have to take the first result with a big grain of salt, point out problems by adding more information, and go through longer conversations about the code, its problems, and the problem you want to solve, in order to get something which *might* be usable. It takes time, but after that time you could have a good base to continue from.

Comment: @BaylorWei Also note that without actual knowledge yourself, such "AI" systems are no better than doing [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Which is a bad thing. If you're a student, it won't really teach you anything useful.